# How can I call another modal overlay on exit

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, overlay

I'm using this script to load some overlay modals that I've created on my site. The modal's a triggered this way:

```
<a class="activate_modal" name="modal_window" href="#">call it now!</a>
```

Now, I want to call another modal (modal_window3) once a user tries to exit from a page by placing a javascript event on the body tag. How can I do this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//get the height and width of the page
var window_width = $(window).width();
var window_height = $(window).height();
//vertical and horizontal centering of modal window(s)
/*we will use each function so if we have more then 1 
modal window we center them all*/
$('.modal_window').each(function(){
    //get the height and width of the modal
    var modal_height = $(this).outerHeight();
    var modal_width = $(this).outerWidth();
    //calculate top and left offset needed for centering
    var top = (window_height-modal_height)/3;
    var left = (window_width-modal_width)/3;
    //apply new top and left css values 
    $(this).css({'top' : top , 'left' : left});
});
    $('.activate_modal').click(function(){
          //get the id of the modal window stored in the name of the activating element       
          var modal_id = $(this).attr('name');
          //use the function to show it
          show_modal(modal_id);
    });
    $('.close_modal').click(function(){
        //use the function to close it
        close_modal();
    });
});
//THE FUNCTIONS
function close_modal(){
    //hide the mask
    $('#mask').fadeOut(500);
    //hide modal window(s)
    $('.modal_window').fadeOut(500);
}
function show_modal(modal_id){
    //set display to block and opacity to 0 so we can use fadeTo
    $('#mask').css({ 'display' : 'block', opacity : 0});
    //fade in the mask to opacity 0.8 
    $('#mask').fadeTo(500,0.8);
     //show the modal window
    $('#'+modal_id).fadeIn(500);
}
```

Comment: would you like to call a event when user try to close/exit from page?

Comment: @Suman-Bogati I want to adapt the function show_modal to show the modal_window3 on exit

Comment: You can't. For security reasons, upon navigating from the page, the browser just accepts a string, as the question you would like to be asked to the user in a native window like JS `confirm()`.